# Password automatically changed after updating it

Tags: python, angularjs, django, authentication

I have a weird bug for some basic features in our website.  Right now, we allow people to sign up and be a user with email, password, name, and birthday.  We also allow them to login to through website and update their information.  However, we recognize that the account password is changed after they have clicked "update". We have the same feature for our iOS app and it works properly. 
I am wondering what would bugs like this be called so that I have a direction to look into. Does it sound like a problem on our website's code, or a problem in the backend?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used ModelForm with User model and custom template by using {{ form.Xxx }}.

If you have used it then it is possible that when you save your ModelForm without password it will be reseted.

Try this in your ModelForm

```
exclude = ['password',]
```